# Drawing along an equation of a line in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a line [from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)] on the canvas that acts like a gun. I want the bullet to travel in the direction of the line (gun). Let the bullet also be a line. I know that from x1, y1 and x2, y2 I can find the slope of the line m and the y-intercept b. I'm also aware that the equation of a line is y = mx + b. I want the bullet to travel along the equation y = mx + b.

---

I do not want my bullet to look like a long line that starts from the end of my gun all the way to the boundary of the canvas. I want it to be a small line redrawn multiple times along the equation y = mx + b.

---

Can someone please guide me on how to draw my bullet's movement? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial This should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple interpolation formula where you animate it by adjusting the factor `f`.

The formula is (shown only for `x`):

```
x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * f
```

An example on how to implement -

**[AN ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/e42k7/)**

```
/// add click callback for canvas (id = demo)
demo.onclick = function(e) {

    /// get mouse coordinate
    var rect = demo.getBoundingClientRect(),

        /// gun at center bottom
        x1 = demo.width * 0.5,
        y1 = demo.height,

        /// target is where we click on canvas
        x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y2 = e.clientY - rect.top,

        /// factor [0, 1] is where we are at the line
        f = 0,

        /// our bullet
        x, y;

    loop();
}
```

Then we provide the following code for the loop

```
function loop() {

    /// clear previous bullet (for demo)
    ctx.clearRect(x - 2, y - 2, 6, 6);

    /// HERE we calculate the position on the line
    x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * f;
    y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * f;

    /// draw some bullet
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 3, 3);


    /// increment f until it's 1
    if (f < 1) {
        f += 0.05;
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(x - 2, y - 2, 6, 6);
    }

}
```

To draw a "longer" bullet that follows the line you can either store an older value of the x/y pair and draw a line between that and current, or less optimal, calculate the position separately or even calculate the angle and use a fixed length.

Also worth to be aware of: the longer the line is the faster the bullet goes. You can calculate a delta value for `f` based on length (not shown in demo) to get around this.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much Ken, this is very educational. Let me try it out and understand it.